# Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us-MongoDB Statefulset on Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I've deployed a Statefulset on Kubernetes for 3 pod mongo replicaset. When I delete a pod,new pod is not able to join the replica set with error "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us-MongoDB Statefulset on Kubernetes"

Comment: You might consider first to look through the similar discussed Stack [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Our+replica+set+config+is+invalid+or+we+are+not+a+member+of+it), pointing to the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the bitnami mongo Statefulset, I use it too. It will be helpful

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb